# how to handle <div id="preloader"> obscuring other elements with selenium, checked other answers nothing helped

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm trying to automate a web application with selenium java and this is the message I keep getting org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element  is not clickable at point (85,37) because another element  obscures it in all the browsers.

I tried all the waits, explicit wait for 20 seconds seems to work but often it fails too. Also, this is happening before almost every element on the application and I think applying explicit wait or Thread.sleep before every element is a good practice.

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Agent Corrections')]")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("preloader")));

    String expectedText = "";
    String actualText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#users_management > div.panel-heading > h4")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedText, actualText);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'')]")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'')]")).click();

    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("preloader")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("pcc")).sendKeys("");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pnr")).sendKeys("");
    driver.findElement(By.id("FFFormSubmit")).click();

    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("preloader")));
```

element obscuring is with div id = preloader

Comment: Can we get page URL?

Comment: You can also check for individual elements to be visible/clickable/interactable before using them. This would be in place of checking for absence of the overlay

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot give you the page URL cause it's under the organisation. However, when I use anything else instead of "invisibility of element located" in explicit wait, it fails. It could also be the issue of the web application not being stable.

Comment: 20+ second wait for every element sounds like a serious issue.  Are you uploading large files?

Comment: No, there are no files. Plus i talked to one of the developers and he ignored the issue by saying this problem is because his code is back end and my script is front end.  Searched a lot but couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: Odd response, but this does seem like a front-end script problem.  Can you post the script for displaying/closing the preloader div?  Sounds like that's waiting for something to happen and it's hitting a timeout or something.

Comment: <!-- Preloader -->
        <div id="preloader">
            <div id="status"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
        </div> This is the preloader element and till now i found only explicit wait to resolve this, however i cannot say it's resolved cause most of the times it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check if the preloader is displayed and then wait for its invisibility. This probably makes the execution bit slower, but it is fail safe.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS) // this will make wait time of 5 seconds for each element including preloader.

WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
 if(driver.findElement(By.id("preloader")).isDisplayed())
{    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("preloader")));
}
```

Comment: I've tried this technique before, but it's not fail safe. With timing you may never find it displayed and then this will break.

Comment: yes. it depends on the application and wait time may need to be adjusted.

Comment: This works faster than my approach, but then again the issue is that exception comes before every element when the page loads. And Thread.sleep is not a good approach to apply before every element cause if I have a larger test script it would take ages for it to be completed.

Comment: You shouldn't mix implicit waits with explicit waits.